# What is the Riemann surface of the exponential integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, riemann-surfaces, complex-integration

I have recently encountered a differential equation whose solution has a term
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} e^{i \tau}} \int_{\tau_0}^\tau e^{\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} e^{i \tau'}} d\tau' \text{ where } \varepsilon \ll 1.
\end{equation}
I believe this integral can be evaluated in terms of the exponential integral, either $\operatorname{Ei}$ or $\operatorname{E}_1$. However, since this term is part of a solution to a differential equation it must depend smoothly on $\tau$, and the exponential integral I know to have branch cuts. I therefore ask: what is the Riemann surface of the exponential
integral?

Comment: There just a logarithmic branch point at the origin, for sure? Go around the origin once, see the function value increase by $\pm2\pi i$.

Comment: If I write the integral as $I(\tau)$, then are you saying $I(\tau + 2 \pi) = I(\tau) + 2 \pi i$? One of my troubles is that making the substitution $z' = - \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} e^{i \tau'}$ in the integral yields the terminals $- \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} e^{i \tau_0}$ and $- \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} e^{i \tau}$, and for $\tau_0 = 0$ and $\tau$ nearby $0$ I'm not sure if this integral converges.

Comment: I was talking about Ei, not the integral in your question. I haven't looked into that at all.

Comment: This will answer your question: https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.4